# Oracle JDBC Properties

Tags: oracle, jdbc, weblogic

I'm maintaining an Oracle 9 database connected to a Java application.

When looking at the weblogic configuration I note that the following properties are set next to the datasource, but I am not sure as to what effect these have. Does anyone know the purpose and effect of the settings below?

- oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible=true
- oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant=false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible  - After 8i the JDBC driver started returning a java.sql.Date class for a DATE type column and a java.sql.Timestamp class for a TIMESTAMP column.  That makes sense except a Oracle DATE column also contains time information so a lot of table designs have DATE for storing timestamps and want a java.sql.Timestamp.  By setting that option, you'll get the old behavior of a DATE column creating a java.sql.Timestamp.

oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant - This one I'm not sure about.  I found a reference that says it turns on a Java EE 1.3 strict mode.  What exactly that means I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

oracle.jdbc.J2EE13Compliant at least make ResultSet.getObject(...) to return java.sql.Timestamp for timestamp database types, instead of proprtietary oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/datacc.htm